# Order of size specifiers in unpacked ports

Tags: arrays, verilog, system-verilog, hdl

I was wondering what is the difference in declaring an unpacked port this way:

```
input logic a[10];
```

or this way:

```
input logic a[9:0];
```

I could not find the difference documented anywhere, I only know by experience that connecting two ports with these "different?" types would not cause any warning (tested in both vcs and modelsim) but the order of data might be reversed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Verilog `input logic a[10]` logic is not allowed and will cause

> Single value range is not allowed in this mode of verilog

error. You need to declare an array using range (i.e. `[9:0]`).

On the other hand, in SystemVerilog you can declare an array using range or size (i.e. `[10]`). Based on [IEEE 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) ch. 7.4.2:

> Each fixed-size dimension shall be represented by an address range (...) or a single positive number to specify the size of a fixed-size unpacked array, as in C. In other words, `[size]`  becomes the same as `[0:size-1]`.